# Dell Latititude 3350 Network Driver

Tags: drivers, dell, realtek, realtek-wireless

I have a Dell Latitude 3350 (Branded as Latitude Education 13") however I can not find the driver for ubuntu anywhere. It does not automatically pre-install and i require Ethernet to effectively connect to some work resources.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `acpi_rev_override` as a kernel boot parameter is a workaround for this.

You do this by editing the config file for GRUB, for example:

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line starting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

and add `acpi_rev_override` to the parameters between quotes, so that you end up with, for example

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_rev_override"
```

Save the file and exit, then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

The parameter will be applied on the next boot.

Comment: Can you please provide a short tutorial for the OP, on how to use the kernel parameter?  A little step by step would be ideal :)